# modified coin toss program won't run

Tags: python

So I have to complete an assignment in which a coin toss is simulated and the number of flips, tails, and heads must be counted.

My first problem was that I could not get the number of heads or tails to display, fixed that, but then it was doubling(ex: I request 50 flips and the total amount of heads and tails would equate to 100), figured out that I had accidentally made it so it was counting up twice instead of once per flip, when I changed that the program just doesn't seem to run.

When I input the amount of times I would like the coin to flip and hit enter it just does nothing and goes to the next line on my terminal. I have removed all white space off my program in case of infinite looping other than that I cannot figure out what is causing this.

Thank you for any help.

[image: code]

[image: what happens in the terminal once I run the program]

Comment: Your start with `tails + heads < count`. What will that condition be initially? Also, in your loop you increment count each time you increment heads or tails. What impact does that have on your loop condition?

Comment: Don't post images please, just copy and paste your code..

Comment: You should not increment count in your loop. Otherwise the sum of tails and heads will never catch up and stop the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove below line, otherwise it will keep on looping

```
count +=1
```

Because, at the same time you are incrementing `head` or `tail` as well.

Assuming, you provided input `1` then, it will check

```
head+tail < count # 0 < 1 , which is true
```

then assuming `coin=1` then,

```
count+=1
head= head+1
```

For the next loop

```
head+tail < count # 1 < 2 , which is true
```

Comment: thank you so much I have been banging my head on this for a few hours now

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you increment your count variable, alongside your head and tails counts. So you are in a while loop aiming for a moving target. I am not attempting to compete with Ravi for the accepted answer, but here is a simplified version of your code.

You needn't use a while loop, as you know how many iterations you will do. In this case a for loop is the appropriate tool.

```
from random import choice


heads = tails = 0
count = int(input('how many flips? '))

for _ in range(count):
    if choice([True, False]):
        heads += 1
    else:
        tails += 1

print('you flipped %d times' % count)
print('you flipped %d heads and %d tails' % (heads, tails))
```